# adjusting plot axis in user defined function - R

Tags: r

I have a function in R which creates a standard normal plot, and then uses a for loop that calls  density plots for the t distribution for various degrees of freedom. The plot looks like:

[image]

Note that the density for degrees of freedom = 2 extends outside of the y axis limits. I am wondering if there is a way to edit the for loop so that the axis limits are adjusted according to the range of the density lines that are drawn.

The for loop code that I am using is as follows:

```
N <- 1000
n <- c(25,50,100,200)
df<-c(1:4,seq(5,25,by=5))

histPlot <- function(data) {
  x <- seq(-4, 4, length=100)
  y <- dnorm(x, mean=0, sd=1)

  plot(x, y, type="l", 
       main=paste("Distribution of size", nrow(data)/9000, sep=" "),
       xlab="standard deviation")
  colors <- brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "Spectral")
  i<-1
  for (d in df) {
    lines(density(data[data$df==d, "t"]),col=colors[i])
    legend("topright", pch=c(21,21), col=c(colors, "black"), legend=c(df, "normal"), bty="o", cex=.8)
    i <- i+1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lines` functions called inside the `for` loop add up to the existing plot.

This means you have to change the `ylim` parameter in the `plot` function call. This will make a higher plot, and lines will be visible when added.

Try like this:

```
plot(x, y, type="l", 
     main=paste("Distribution of size", nrow(data)/9000, sep=" "),
     xlab="standard deviation",
     ylim = c(0, 1)) # This line will make the plot higher, i.e. the y axis range will be from 0 to 1
```